# How to split csv data in two parts.?

Tags: php, file, csv, export-to-csv, multiple-tables

Is it possible to export csv data in to two parts:

From the below image i have two things to be considered
1. summery 
2. Detail information

I worked with only 2nd type is it possible to do like 2 batches(like shown in image)..?

please suggest any alternate idea if you got.

Example:

**summary header**

```
$titleSummery = array('Course Name','Average watched','semi watched','notwached','sudents attempted','sudents notattempted','Total students','Branch','passout');
/*summery data */
```

**Details header**

```
$titleDetail = array('student','passout','branch','percentage watched','student email');
/*Details data */
```

> In this case how can i export the data..?

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, $title);

foreach($data as $k=>$res){
fputcsv($output,$res);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare array for each line. see my inline comments.

```
$titleSummery = array('Course Name','Average watched','semi watched','notwached','sudents attempted','sudents notattempted','Total students','Branch','passout');
$titleSummeryData = array('Number System','50%','40%',....); // fill remaining data.
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// put first table
foreach($titleSummery as $key=>$val){
 fputcsv($output,array($val,$titleSummeryData[$key]));
}
// begin second table
// put all title/header
fputcsv($output,$titleDetail);
// For second table i assume that you have data in 2D array 
foreach($titleDetailsData as $row){
 fputcsv($output);
}
fclose($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You direction is good, you just need to understand that each call to fputcsv prints a line, so you'll need to call it for each row in the first batch of data also, for example:

```
fputcsv($output,"course name","php for dummies");
```